# Difference between lsof and ulimit -a

Tags: files, ulimit, lsof

I have a problem in my jaxws-service and it returns the error:

> too many open files

I wanted to monitor open files. When I inserted lsof, a file used by tomcat is returning a number that is higher than `ulimit -a` outputs as open files, but tomcat doesn't say that there are too many open files.

Output of `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39838
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39838
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited`
```

And the output of

```
lsof | grep /test/test/test/test/test-test/test/test/test/test.properties | wc -l
```

is `7334`.

As you can see, the lsof value is higher than `ulimit -n`, but no "too many open files" error occurred. Now I want to know how to monitor the count of open files and when the error "too many open file" would occur.

Comment: `ulimt -n` shows a per-process limit I think; the *total* number of open files may be much higher (up to the value shown by `sysctl fs.file-max`)

Comment: It seems this command is that I wanted. Thanks @steeldriver.